# Ought we more efficiently make the question title match the substantive question?

Tags: discussion, editing

There was debate on [Has scholarship shown that persecuted religious minorities have tended to be financially successful?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8290/is-it-true-that-persecuted-religious-minorities-have-tended-to-be-financially-su) due to the question's title not matching the question's content.

Ought we as users more regularly edit other's questions to ensure that the title match the body?  Ought we more often look to see if the question matches the title when reading in passing.

Answer (score 7):

I would say yes. It is both the responsibility of the OP, and of the community, to work towards the best questions possible. If a question's content deviates severely from the title then it is much more incumbent on the user to fix that error. However, tweaking is something that is inherent in the Stack model. What you don't want to do is change the title, or content, to not reflect the author's intention.

Comment: +1 - I agree with this observation.

Comment: I was the OP of that question, and I agree with this. If there's an unambiguous improvement to be made, it should be made. If there's any doubt you can always ask the OP (by calling it to their attention with an @ reference).

Comment: Totally agree. The caveat is if it's NOT crystal clear whether one or the other is correct, you need to make an effort to ask OP.